# SwiftUI List on macOS prematurely loads every row

Tags: macos, cocoa, swiftui, appkit, swiftui-list

I'm observing a weird issue with `SwiftUI` `List`s on macOS (they do work as expected on iOS). The problem is that the `List` calls the `init` & `body` of every row, even if those rows are not on screen (and might never be shown).

If I replace the `List` with a `ScrollView` + `LazyVStack`, it does work as expected (only those rows which are going to be rendered get their `init` & `body` called). Of course, this is is not an ideal workaround because you loose the built-in benefits of using a `List` (mainly selection in my case).

I did expect that under the hood, `SwiftUI` would use the same mechanism as `NSTableView` (which loads cells on demand). Historically I'm an iOS dev, so I'm used to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` coming from `UITableView`.

Here's a quick gist demonstrating the issue:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SwiftUIListVSLazyVStackApp: App {

    let numbers = (0...100).map { $0 }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            /*
             List calls the init & the body of *every* element on the list, even if it's not being displayed.
             This is unexpected because a tableView usually only loads the visible cells as needed (cellForRowAtIndexPath)
             */
            List(numbers) { number in
                RowView(for: number, example: "list")
            }

            /*
             A combination of ScrollView + LazyVStack achieves what's expected from the list. Only calls the init & body of
             the element that's going to be displayed.
             */
//            ScrollView {
//                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
//                    ForEach(numbers) { number in
//                        RowView(for: number, example: "stack")
//                    }
//                }
//            }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {

    private let number: Int
    private let example: String

    init(for number: Int, example: String) {
        print("Init \(example): \(number)")
        self.number = number
        self.example = example
    }

    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("Body \(example): \(number)")
        Text("\(number)")
            .onAppear{ print("Appear \(example): \(number)") }
    }
}

extension Int: Identifiable {
    public var id: Int { self }
}
```

GitHub gist: https://gist.github.com/xmollv/7ecc97d8118c100e85698c5ff09a20dc

And a video to better show the issue if you can't run the code:
https://gist.github.com/xmollv/7ecc97d8118c100e85698c5ff09a20dc?permalink_comment_id=4140623#gistcomment-4140623

Twitter thread: https://twitter.com/xmollv/status/1517158777882955779

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: That’s why they add LazyVStack. It is explain in the [dic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack) that List load all list contents but LazyVStack only when needed.

Comment: Try to move everything into separated root view - it can be the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919820/12299030.

Comment: @PtitXav I doubt that `LazyVStack` was added as a replacement for `List`s when you need better performance. Without using a `List`, you need to implement all the default expected behaviors for selecting on a list manually, swipe left/right, etc. Also, I couldn't find anywhere that lists load all its contents at once. Coming from `UIKit` & `UITableView`, that would be a surprise. Could you link me to the correct documentation?

-

@Asperi I've tried that suggestion and sadly the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: @XaviMoll . It wrote what I understood from [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/creating-performant-scrollable-stacks) . It state that for performance or is better to use LazyStack. I supposed that List may be reserved for smaller size of data. May be I am wrong.

Comment: @PtitXav I think that the comment refers to _focused container types_, not to _collection container_ like `List`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/collection-containers. This looks more like a bug with the `SwiftUI` <-> `AppKit` interface than anything else, it doesn't make any sense that lists are so bad performance-wise when they do work as expected on `UIKit` and if you replace them for a `LazyVStack` the performance is as expected (but you loose a ton of built in functionality)

Comment: Are you facing a performance issue? One of the reasons AppKit/UIKit tables load their rows lazily was that creating each one is computationally expensive. However, creating structs is much cheaper. SwiftUI doesn't necessarily create all of the actual user interface elements until needed. That's why you should defer any expensive operations to onAppear/task modifiers, whose lifecycle more closely resembles the AppKit/UIKit events. You can mitigate in various ways if performance truly is an issue, but in my experience keeping your view inits light gets you a much bigger return on your dev time

Comment: @ScottMatthewman Yes, actually that's why I came up to realizing this. I've an app that uses Core Data + `@FetchRequest`. There are times where there are 10.000 items to display on the list or more. When using a `List`, the performance is horrendous, literally taking ~5 seconds for the initial load. If I change it for the `ScrollView` + `LazyVStack` combo, the rendering is instant (as one would expect). On iOS, `List` work as they do on `UIKit`, the `init` & `body` are only called when they're going to be rendered, not sure why macOS differs on this or if there's any way to prevent it.

Comment: Here are two related articles about list slowness that might be of interest, https://kean.blog/post/not-list and https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui

Comment: @ScottMatthewman To expand on your question, here's a quick demo displaying `100_000` items on the lists. It's only rendering a `Text`, with a very simple `init`, so that should not be an issue. The performance between the two is astonishing: https://gist.github.com/xmollv/7ecc97d8118c100e85698c5ff09a20dc?permalink_comment_id=4141501#gistcomment-4141501

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for the links! I had read those before, and from what I'm seeing online, it seems that `List`s on macOS are kinda _broken_. I was hoping that somebody new about a workaround, but doesn't look like it.

Comment: I've tested some options and not come up with a way to make List work well for lots of data. My guess is that UITableView has lazy loading but NSTableView does not, so a List is lazy on iOS but not on macOS. But your solution works fine and is what I would use.